# Make a folder shared for anonymous login

Tags: dns, windows-server-2003, network-share, workgroup, shared-directory

I have a folder on a windows server 2003 machine in a workgroup that I want to share with a server 2008 machine that is in a domain. I want that to be accessed without prompting for logon credentials.

I shared the directory with the users 'EveryOne','Anonymous Login','Guest' with read permissions. Now when I try to access the shared location \\machineip\share_dir 
I get the error  -

"check the spelling of the name. otherwise there might be a problem with your network"

Can someone help here?

Comment: Is the 2003 a part of the domain?

Comment: No that is not part of the domain..

Comment: what it shows if you type \\mashineip ?

Comment: it does show me the shared directory when i just try \\machineip .. But when I try to open that directory i get the error msg that i mentioned..

Comment: hm. and what is the content of security tab on properties for this folder?